# How to send to a group based on graduation year

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions

I would like to create a data extension with all of our student population.  The user would then send an email to a subset of that group based on the year that the student graduated.  I am hoping there is an easy way to do this instead of creating a filter for each graduating year from 1980 forward.  Thank you!

Comment: Please update your question to include details about your Student data extension. What fields would you want in the resulting data extension?

Answer (score 2):

If these are occasional manual sends, you'd probably be best to just filter the data extension. It's a lot of data extensions yes, but they are all separate segments of people that you want to send to.

Comment: Unlike an automatable campaign (like "contact students 5 years after graduation to push for donations"), it sounds like there's no real logic behind the selection of the year, and as such I'd agree with Baneen that the simplest way to manage this would be with Filtered Data Extensions. This would give you the most flexibility around selection criteria and avoid the technical debt of a more complex, SQL-based solution.

Comment: Thank you Baneen and Rainer!  I was hoping it wouldn't come to that.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to get all students that graduate in the current year, here's a sargable Query Activity example:

```sql
select
  s.firstName
, s.graduation_date
from Students s
where s.graduation_date > dateadd(yy, datediff(yy, 0, getdate()), 0) 
/* name: Students_Graduating_This_Year */
/* target: Students_Graduating_This_Year */
/* action: overwrite */
/* notes: student graduation date is after the first day of the current year */
```

Comment: Thank you but the user needs to be able to pick a specific year, anywhere from 1980-2020.  For example, a classmate from 1999 passes away.  They want to be able to notify everyone that graduated in 1999.

Comment: Please update your question with details about your Student data extension.  Is the graduation "date" an actual date or just the year?